# Bounded linear transformation subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

H,G are inner products spaces ( . , .) over a subfield $C$ and field $F$.  I have that $L_b(H,G)$ is the set of all bounded elements of $L(H,G)$.  I am supposed to show that $T \in L_b(H,G)$ is a subspace of $T \in L(H,G)$.

My attempt:  Well I know that I need to show it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  So I have $T_1,T_2 \in L_b(H,G)$ and $\alpha \in F$

$||(\alpha T_1+T_2)(x)|| = ||\alpha T_1(x)+T_2(x)||$

$\leq  |\alpha| ||T_1(x)|| + ||T_2(x)||$

$\leq |\alpha| ||T_1|| |x| + ||T_2|| |x|$

= $K ||x||$

where $K=|\alpha| ||T_1||+||T_2||$

So $\alpha T_1 + T_2$ is a bounded operator and thus a subspace of $L(H,G)$.  Have I done this correctly?